# Stop exponential values in table

Tags: python, heatmap, crosstab, exponential

When building a heatmap in seaborn, is there a way to stop exponential values appearing:
'''
count_table = pd.crosstab(df["Exited"], df["NumOfProducts"])
sns.heatmap(count_table, annot=True, center=0.5)
'''

The output gets values like 3.345e+03

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to the format of the numbers in the cells. You can use the fmt argument to control the formatting, for example

```
sns.heatmap(count_table, annot=True, fmt=".1f")
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfectly thank you.  Funny how something so frustrating has such a simple answer when shown!  Thanks again.